# Let $F$ be a field, let $E=F(a)$ be a simple extension field of $F$, and let $b\in E-F$. Prove that $a$ is algebraic over $F(b)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Question: Let $F$ be a field, let $E=F(a)$ be a simple extension field of $F$, and let $b\in E-F$.  Prove that $a$ is algebraic over $F(b)$.

I think I have the right idea, but I am getting hung up on the definition of the field of fractions.  So, as $E=F(a)$, we have that $E=\{\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}:f(x),g(x)\in F[x], g(a)\neq 0\}$.  So then as $b\in E-F$, $b=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, so if we let $h(x)=bg(x)-f(x)\in F(b)[x]$, then if $h(a)=0$, we'd be done.  But, by the definition of field of fractions, isn't $g(a)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion, let $f,g\in F[x]$ be such that $g(a)\neq0$ and $b=\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$. To show that $a$ is algebraic over $F(b)$ you need to show that $h(a)=0$ for some nonzero $h\in(F(b))[y]$.

Because $b\notin F$ we have either $\deg f>0$ or $\deg g>0$, or both. Hence $h=bg(y)-f(y)$ is nonzero and does the trick.

Comment: I suppose my confusion lies because we want that $h(a)=0$, but as $g(a)\neq0$, how does $bg(a)-f(a)=0$ if the first term is nonzero?

Comment: Because the second is also nonzero. The first term in $(1+\sqrt{2})^2-(3+2\sqrt{2})$ is also nonzero, but the whole is still zero.